# how should I use system command in perl

Tags: perl, sed

I want to replace a line with the $var.
runnew has

```
input= input/old/should/change;
replace= input/old/replace;
other = input/old/other;
replace_other= input/old/replace_other;
```

My output file should look like,

```
 input= input/old/should/New;
replace= input/old/New_replace;
other = input/old/New_other;
replace_other= input/old/New_replace_other;
```

I want to replace "input =" by  input = input/old/should/New;
 I have used like,

```
if ($#ARGV != 0) {
    die "\n********USAGE <cellname> <tech>********\n"; 
}
$newinput=$ARGV[0];
open(my $fh, "$runnew") or die "Could not open rerun.txt: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
 system ( sed -i "/input=.*/c\input= $newinput" $runnew );
}
```

But there is error popping up "Scalar found where operator expected at run.pl" and its displaying sed line and asking " (Missing operator before  $runnew?)."
When I used same sed on terminal its replacing the line .

Please can anyone point out where the error is ?

Yes Using Sed is simple but I have file with different lines and each line should be replaced . 
Please let me knoe if you have better idea than this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use Perl for the chosen approach? Wouldn't the simple shell one-liner `sed -i '/input=.*/c\input= <REPLACEMENT>' $(input_file.txt)` be much simpler?

Comment: If you *do* want to use Perl, why don't you use Perl directly for updating the files?

Comment: You're trying to call sed to do an identical in-place edit of a file you're currently reading lines from, for every line you read? Um... Even after fixing the syntax errors that doesn't make any sense. Why not do it all in Perl, or just one sed invocation?

Comment: Anyways, `system()` is a function, not a quote-like operator. What you're passing it is not a valid perl expression; of course you're getting syntax errors.

Comment: If you want to use `perl` instead of `sed`, try this command: `perl -pse 's/input=.*/$newinput/' -- -newinput=<REPLACEMENT> rerun.txt`

Comment: This question seems to basically be "I don't know perl. Teach me perl.", which is a rather broad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system()` takes a list of strings as its argument. You you need to put quotes around the command you pass it.

```
system ( "sed -i '/input=.*/c\input= $newinput' $runnew" );
```

But your code still looks very strange. You're running exactly the same `sed` command for every line in the input file. Is that what you meant to do?

It's not really clear what you're trying to do here. But I'm confident that the best approach would involve **not** using `sed` and using Perl to make your transformations.

Comment: I have used "quotes but still problem exists.

Comment: @Anthonyj: Then I assume there's something wrong in the way you're using the quotes. But unless you edit your question and show us what you've done, I'm unsure how I can help you :-)

Comment: I have edited my question ,please look once. And I tried   system as  system ( "sed -i "/input=.*/c\input= $newinput" $runnew " ); . @Dave Cross

Comment: @Anthonyj: You haven't edited your question to show us what you've tried with quotes, have you? Please do that. Reading code in comments is hard.

Comment: @Anthonyj: Oh, wait. It looks like you added double quotes around the `sed` command, but didn't change the inner ones to single quotes. Perhaps compare what you have with what I actually put in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to call `sed` at all? Your requirement can be much easier handled in Perl directly:

- add `-i.bak` to enable in-place replacement mode
- use the first command line parameter as replacement string

  - remove it from the `@ARGV` array so it will not be interpreted as file
- loop over all files on the command line

  - read line by line
  - apply substitution
  - print result

Perl automatically takes care of opening the files, writing to the correct file and renaming old files to `.bak`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak
use warnings;
use strict;

my($replacement) = shift(@ARGV);

while (<>) {
    s/input=.*/input= $replacement/;
    print;
}

exit 0;
```

Test run (taking an educated guess on your input data):

```
$ cat dummy1.txt.bak 
input= test1
input= test2
$ cat dummy2.txt.bak 
input= test3
input= test4

$ perl dummy.pl REPLACEMENT dummy1.txt dummy2.txt

$ cat dummy1.txt
input= REPLACEMENT
input= REPLACEMENT
$ cat dummy2.txt
input= REPLACEMENT
input= REPLACEMENT
```

or to use the contents of the file "rerun.txt":

```
$ perl dummy.pl REPLACEMENT $(cat rerun.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan-becker its working . But is it doing only  on terminal and I should redirect to another file ? .

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you mean. You want to read all files and then dump all lines, possibly modified by the substitution, to one file? That would contradict what you wrote in your question.

Comment: As I have specified in the question I have different lines to replace  , So Im reading each line and replacing it .

Comment: I see you edited your question, but IMHO the problem description is not much clearer. Your desired output indicates that you want to insert `New_` before the last word of each line in `runnew`? Or?

Comment: @ Stefan Becker Or you can say that I want to replace everything after equal sign .

Comment: But you are not saying what you replace it with. Therefore it is impossible to answer your question. Otherwise you would have already accepted my answer, because it replaces everything after `=`.

Comment: Yes your answer serves the purpose.

Comment: Then please accept it so that your question no longer appears as unanswered. Thank you.